# VueJS - Custom Component Reactivity Messed Up

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been using VueJS very happily for some months now. As an aside, the Elements UI package is great! Hence the `class="el-button"` to make the link look like a button.

I've created lots of custom components without issues, however, I created a simple download button, and when there is one per DIV (I suspect) everything is fine. I have a complex form with many panels and all work OK, but when there are two in the same section, it freaks out the reactivity.

However, after a lot of teeth gnashing with a a very odd bug, where I have two download buttons on the same page, the 2nd one doesn't look at the props passed to it, it gets confused an uses the **first** download button's props.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but for the life of me, can't see where.

The rationale for the component is to download a file from a Laravel backend, that the user has uploaded earlier.

`AjaxMixins` is a wrapper for some `axios` calls to the backend.

The full code of the component is below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="!fileName">
      <i @click="this.console.log('DL fileList', fileList, 'current', current, 'files', files)">{{text}} not available</i>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <strong><a class="el-button" :href="url"
        :download="fileName">
        <i :class="'el-icon-' + icon"></i>{{text}} - {{fileName}} </a></strong>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import AjaxMixins from '@/mixins/AjaxMixins'

export default {
  mixins: [AjaxMixins],

  props: {
    fileList: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },

    text: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Download'
    },

    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: 'view'
    },

    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'plain'
    },

    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },

    afterDownload: {
      type: Function
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      isDisabled: this.disabled,
      files: this.fileList
    }
  },


  computed: {

    current: function () {
      return (this.files && this.files.length > 0) ? 0 : null
    },

    url: function () {
      if (typeof this.current === 'number' && this.files[this.current].response) {
        return this.getEndpoint('file/download/' + this.files[this.current].response.path + '/' + this.fileName)
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }, // url


    fileName: function () {
      if (typeof this.current === 'number') {
        return this.files[this.current].name
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.files = this.fileList
  }
}

</script>
```

What I've noticed is that although the `fileList` prop shows correctly, for some reason the `files` local version has nothing.

Comment: Please show where the component is used.

Comment: Thanks for replying Bert.
      <div v-if="isClient()">
        <el-form-item label="">
          <file-download :file-list="rts.state.step4.uploadAgreement"
          icon="document" type="success"
          :text="'Download ' + rts.state.step4.docType"
         />
        </el-form-item>
      </div>

      <div v-else>
      <el-form-item label="">
        <file-download :file-list="rts.state.step4.uploadSignedAgreement"
        icon="document" type="success"
        :text="'Download Signed ' + rts.state.step4.docType"
        />
      </el-form-item>
    </div>

Comment: Apologies for the messed up code- can't seem to edit the question right now to add the use case. Short version: if client, they can download and upload certain docs.

If the other party, they can download what the client uploaded and upload other files.

Comment: I've got a temporary workaround by putting the link code directly into the page- which works. It's messy but at least the project is not stalled by this issue.